# How does (x, y).GetHashCode() work behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, .net, hashcode, c#-7.0

```
public class Lemon{
   public int Ounces;
   public string Color;

   public override int GetHashCode() => (Ounces, Color).GetHashCode();
}
```

I'm curious on how that works.  The `(Ounces, Color)` is similar to an anonymous type, but doesn't share the same syntax. And if it were an anonymous type then I'm still unsure how it'd know to get a unique hash.

A link to the relevant .net source code would be great.  It's difficult to uncover since i'm unsure of what type the `(Ounces, Color)` ends up being compiled into.

Comment: That syntax, `(A, B)` is a tuple from C# 7.

Comment: @Adrian: The type would be `ValueTuple<T1, T2>`, not `Tuple<T1. T2>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(Ounces, Color)` is a tuple, which were introduced in C# 7. The corresponding type is `ValueTuple<T1, T2>`. From the [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Test/Resources/Core/NetFX/ValueTuple/ValueTuple.cs), you can tell that `GetHashCode()` is calculating the hash code by combining the hash codes of each object (and an additional random seed) using

```
 public static int Combine(int h1, int h2)
 {
     uint rol5 = ((uint)h1 << 5) | ((uint)h1 >> 27);
     return ((int)rol5 + h1) ^ h2;
 }
```

Comment: good catch for the source, and for the short but to the point answer

Comment: Doesn't the random seed mean that `(X, Y).GetHashCode` should not be used for the `GetHashCode` of a custom class that has `Equals(other) => other.X == X && other.Y == Y` ??

Comment: @minseong: The random seed is static and readonly, and shared across all ValueTuple instances, so ValueTuples maintain equality semantics within a running instance of an application. Just don't try to persist the result of GetHashCode and expect it to be meaningful after an application restart.